# How to update initialState when using useState with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to update the image value of the local state which works fine but when I return back to the same page for some reason the initialState retains the previous value. So to fix the issue I have to assign the value separately. It does not look right to me. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

**Initializing the state**

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);
```

**Updating the image value**

```
setValues((values) => {
   const allUploadedFiles = values.images;
   allUploadedFiles.push(data);
   return { ...values, images: allUploadedFiles };
});
```

**Changing the state to initial value**

```
setValues({ ...values, images: [] });
initialState.images = [];
```

**Value of the initial state on declaration**

```
const initialState = {
  images: []
}
```

Comment: What is your `initialState` set to when you declare `values`?

Comment: @cpppatrick question updated

Comment: I have 2 observations for when you change the state.
`setValues({ ...values, images: [] })` should be sufficient to update the state, unless it is an expensive computation. In this case, the state may be updated unexpectedly.
Why would you do `intialState.images=[]`? it doesn't make sence.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a little more context?

I think your `initialState` and `useState()` declaration is fine.

But you shouldn't need to reset `initialState.images`, because it should be that way by default.

Is the problem that when you call `setValues`, that `values` and `initialState` are both updated and contain the same data? And that's why you have to reset `initialState`?

Comment: I added the code snippet that shows where I am adding images. initialState is updated and contains the same data. Exactly, that is why I have to reset the initialState.